# Unable to disable Code Lens in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1

Tags: intellij-idea, development-environment, disabled-control

I have tried both the two ways as below.

1. From Settings > Editor > General > Appearance
2. By right-clicking on scrollbar

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open bug, please [follow for updates](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170552).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will follow it.

Comment: Bug appears to be fixed in version 2017.3 (173.3727.127)